# How to disable controls in a TdxRibbon (DevExpress ribbon control)?

Tags: delphi, devexpress, ribbon

I have a DevExpress VCL ribbon in my Delphi app
From time to time the app is doing some updates and in that period I need to be sure that the user doesn't do anything so I would like to be able to disable all controls on the ribbon but I can't get the count of controls on each tab to work

The ComponentCount returns 0 regardless how I do but I can see controls.
My testcode is looking like this:

```
procedure TfrmMain.RibbonDisable(var aMessage: TMessage);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  try
    for i := 0 to ribMain.TabCount - 1 do
      begin
        ribMain.Tabs.Items[i].Active := True;
        ShowMessage(IntToStr(ribMain.ActiveTab.ComponentCount));
      end;
  except
    on E:exception do
      Logfile.Error('frmMain.RibbonDisable: ' + E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: What version of VCL DevExpress ?

Comment: maybe they want you to use actions.

Comment: @Warren P   I am not sure what you mean by actions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply disable the whole [`TdxRibbon`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2500) while the updates are being performed:

```
ribMain.Enabled := False;
```

Or if you really want to disable only the tab items, use the following:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to ribMain.BarManager.ItemCount - 1 do
    ribMain.BarManager.Items[I].Enabled := False;
end;
```

It is common to almost every toolbar control that you are disabling actions, not what is displayed.

Comment: I used the second solution as it indicates to the user that something is hapening (the buttons are greyed)